# WP: how to query posts by variations?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to do a query my wocommerce products by their variations, so I did:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'flower-type', // attribute slug
    'meta_value' => 'fresh-roses', // attribute value
    'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

else :

    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );

endif;
```

but unfortunately I always get no results, so what is the issue here?

Comment: Your args is not correct see -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of data is saved in a dynamic created meta key so the attribute name counts when making the query, in your case I assumed the slug for your attribute name is "flower-type", you can check this in your database to confirm.

The meta key that you want to use is compose out of the word `attribute` and the name of the attribute you created when making the variations `fresh-flowers` in your case.

Be careful that changing this in the admin will "break" your query.

So the arguments will look like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',  
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'attribute_flower-type',
            'value'   => 'fresh-roses',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
```

please notice the compare attribute used, it might work with `=` but first confirm that it works with `LIKE` and then you can play with it.

Comment: yes you are right, the attribute name in db was 'attribute_pa_flower-type'

Answer (score 0):

Try below argument for passing into WP query:

```
args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',  
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'flower-type',
            'value'   => 'fresh-roses',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: can you check var_dump or last query run through wp query and check what do you get in result?